# Portable app not working when netcoreapp1.0 section moved to frameworks

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.0 with preview 2 tooling.

I moved the netcoreapp1.0 section from dependencies to netcoreapp1.0 in frameworks like so:

`"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "type": "platform"
      }
    }
  }`

Now when I deploy the app, it complains about there is no runtimes section specifying an RID. And when I add that it is deployed as a self-contained app.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project.json should look like this (notice the `dependencies` property):

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      }
  }
```

Because your reference to `Microsoft.NETCore.App` was not inside `dependencies` it could not be found and your application was treated as a standalone app.